# Acessar a instancia da classe principal a partir de uma anônima em PHP 7

Tags: php, php-7

Estou tentando acessar a instancia da classe onde contém uma anônima como fazemos em Java, exemplo:

JAVA

```
class MyClass 
{
    private String prop = "test";

    public void test()
    {
        new Runnable() {

            public void run() 
            {
                // Consigo acessar prop a partir daqui
                System.out.println(MyClass.this.prop);
            }

        }.run();
    }
}
```

PHP 7

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    private $prop = "test";

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class{

            public function run() 
            {
                // ???? como acessar MyClass::$prop daqui de dentro?
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Como acessar a instancia de MyClass de dentro da anônima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação oficial](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.anonymous.php):

> Aninhar uma classe anônima dentro de outra classe não dá acesso a nenhum método privado ou protegido, ou propriedades da classe externa. Para utilizar os métodos e propriedades protegidas da classe externa, a classe anônima pode estender a classe externa. Para utilizar as propriedades privadas da classe externa na classe anônima, elas devem ser passadas através do construtor.

Ou seja, deve ser definido o construtor da classe anônima passando os valores privados a serem utilizado. Por exemplo:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    private $prop = "teste";

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class($this->prop) {

            public function __construct($prop)
            {
                $this->prop = $prop;
            }

            public function run() 
            {
                echo $this->prop, PHP_EOL;
            }

        };

        $class->run();
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/vVVF1B)

Perceba que é o valor desejado que deve ser passado através do construtor. Passar o objeto `$this` como parâmetro e tentar acessar o atributo privado do mesmo dentro da classe anônima resulta em um erro fatal. Veja abaixo:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    private $prop = "teste";

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class($this) {

            public function __construct($obj)
            {
                $this->obj = $obj;
            }

            public function run() 
            {
                echo $this->obj->prop, PHP_EOL;
            }

        };

        $class->run();
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZbKczY).

Ou seja, mesmo passando o próprio objeto e utilizando-o para acessar o atributo privado dentro da própria classe, resulta em erro. Isso porquê o PHP interpreta o contexto da classe anônima como algo isolado da classe pai, não atribuindo-lhe as permissões de acesso aos atributos e métodos privados do próprio objeto.

#### Atributo mutável ou imutável

Se o atributo passado à classe anônima for imutável, esta não terá como alterar o valor original do atributo na classe pai, salvo quando passado o valor por referência. Por padrão, os atributos imutáveis são **passados por valor** no PHP. Para verificar, basta tentar alterar o valor de `$prop` dentro da classe anônima e depois verificar o valor deste atributo na classe pai:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public $prop = "teste";

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class($this->prop) {

            public function __construct($prop)
            {
                $this->prop = $prop;
            }

            public function run() 
            {
                $this->prop = "teste na classe anônima";

                echo $this->prop, PHP_EOL;
            }

        };

        $class->run();
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();

echo $obj->prop, PHP_EOL;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/JbqRmz).

A saída produzida é:

```
teste na classe anônima
teste
```

Ou seja, como o atributo é uma *string* e é um tipo imutável, o valor foi passado para a classe anônima como valor e não foi alterado na classe pai. Basicamente o objeto foi copiado quando passado à classe anônima e esta não possui a referência ao objeto original.

Já, se o valor for de um tipo mutável, um objeto da classe Foo, por exemplo, o comportamento é diferente:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    public function __construct($prop) {
        $this->prop = $prop;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->prop;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->prop = new Foo("test");
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class($this->prop) {

            public function __construct($prop)
            {
                $this->prop = $prop;
            }

            public function run() 
            {
                $this->prop->prop = "Teste na classe anônima";
                echo $this->prop, PHP_EOL;
            }

        };

        $class->run();
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();

echo $obj->prop, PHP_EOL;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/mous1Z).

O resultado produzido é:

```
Teste na classe anônima
Teste na classe anônima
```

Ou seja, o valor original do atributo na classe pai também foi alterado. Uma vez que o objeto passado à classe anônima é mutável, o objeto é **passado por referência**, então qualquer alteração feita dentro da classe anônima afetará, também, o objeto na classe pai, pois são o mesmo objeto.

Comment: O grande problema é o encapsulamento só poderemos usar de dentro das anônimas os publicos, levando-nos para os velhos getters e setters, o PHP ainda precisa amadurecer bastante.

Comment: Não sei se definir como problema é o correto. Seria preciso avaliar semanticamente se realmente faz sentido uma classe anônima ter acesso aos dados privados da classe. Tem o link da documentação do Java sobre isso?

Comment: Como programador para android eu uso isso bastante por conta dos "listeners" e de dentro de um "listener" eu tenho acesso a membros da classe principal com MyClass.this.prop, isso ai é o básico do Java

Answer (score 1):

Acho que não tem como fazer essa referencia, mas pode-se passar um parâmetro para o construtor da classe anónima , por exemplo :

```
class MyClass
{
    private $prop = "test";

    public function test()
    {
        $class = new class($this->prop){

            protected $prop;
            public function __construct($prop){
                $this->prop = $prop;
            }
            public function run() 
            {
                echo $this->prop;
            }

        };

        $class->run(); //test
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu postei no SO em inglês e de fato todos apontaram esta solução de passar no construtor, infelizmente o PHP vem tentando copiar Java e outras, mas ainda é apenas um bebê dando os primeiros passos